# CFdirectory tag doesnot display files in a directory even if the files appear in the source folder

Tags: directory, coldfusion, filenotfoundexception, directory-listing, cfdirectory

I am trying to read a spreadsheet from a shared location folder. using

```
<cfparam name="xlfilepath" type="string" default="\\file02\OP\!FILE STRUCTURES and FORMS\Agreements\Tracker.xls" />
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#xlfilepath#" excludeHeaderRow="true" query="MsaDataSheet1" sheet="1" />
```

"OP" is the shared folder.

I got "java.io.FileNotFoundException:".Then I try to display the directory listing using cfdirectory tag.

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="\\file02\OP\" recurse="false" name="myList">
<cfdump var="#myList#"><cfabort>
```

I see that there is no list displayed although there are subdirectories and folders and files in the OP directory.

Does the folder needs any specific permissions to be read by any application or any other mapping required?

Comment: Can you try `cfdirectory action="list"` with `recurse="true"` and see if the file shows up there?

Comment: The ColdFusion application doesn't have enough permission to access the shared directory. But, the user by which you have login to the system have rights to access the shared directory.

Comment: What are the permissions required to access shared directory?

Comment: Are you just Reading the spreadsheet, or will your application modify it also? And what type of file system?

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdirectory.html

Comment: https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/adobe_coldfusion_11/2016-09-21/finding/V-62433

Answer (score 4):

Here I will explain by using cf16. The ColdFusion runs in Windows as a service and if we look into all the services of the machine we will find as follow:

[image]

Here, you can notice that for ColdFusion service the **LogOnAs** value is "LocalSyatem". It means ColdFusion service is started as "LocalSystem" login and this login doesn't have enough permission to do any operation on network. So, in order to make the required file operation in the Shared Directory we will have to change the **LogOnAs** value for ColdFusion service.
Please follow the below step to enable it,

1. Right Click on the ColdFusion Service then click on "**properties**".
2. Click on "**Log On**" tab. Then you will see a screen like this
3. Select "This account" radio button .Then click on "**Browse**" button
   and select the user by which you want to start the service. You
   should choose the user **who have sufficient permission to create file
   on the shared directory and also have required permission in local**.

[image]

But we have to restart the ColdFusion Service for the changes to effect.

Let me know if this work to you or not. Or correct me if I'm wrong understood.

Comment: One more addition: I would create a specific user that can do only the things they need to do rather than give access to a user who can do whatever they want. Granting access to an Admin-type user is easier, but if that application is breached, that user can be abused to do all sorts of bad things. Limit exposure.

Comment: 100% what @Shawn says. Kennan, consider updating your answer with a step to create a limited access CF user.

Comment: The StigViewer link I posted above has a pretty good walkthrough for creating a CF-specific user on both Windows and Linux.  https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/adobe_coldfusion_11/2016-09-21/finding/V-62433 And the step up from that gives the full STIG for CF11. There's some good info in there for locking down other pieces. Then, there's always Pete Freitag's Lockdown Guides (various versions here https://cfdocs.org/security).